# What does "STA-ASSOC" mean?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking, encryption

Looking at the wireless statistics on a TL-WR740N wireless router, I sometimes see the MAC address "00-20-00-A5-22-1A" connecting, with the current status being "STA-ASSOC".

The [manual](http://www.atel.com.pl/doc/UM_TL-WR740N.pdf) actually shows exactly this current status as example on page 52.
I don't know this MAC address, and it has sent packets to the router, but I haven't seen received packets yet.

The router uses WPA/WPA2 with AES as encryption, which is what it shows when my workstation connects to the router.

Does anyone know what STA-ASSOC is, and if someone have access to the router?

Comment: I would think it's "Status: Associated"

Comment: @l0c0b0x : The manual also lists something called STA-JOINED. Does that make sense in this conjunction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Station associated.  Not sure what device it is though.

Comment: What could that mean? Perhaps another wireless nearby?

Answer (score 6):

Hi I just found out what it is:

STA-ASSOC is a device that was already associate to the wi-fi router and is standing by connection (trying to connect-password changed maybe).

STA-AUTH - device awaiting authorization from router (maybe you had changed the password and the device is trying to reconnect but with the wrong password).

Answer (score 1):

[00-20-00-A5-22-1A](http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/?string=00-20-00-A5-22-1A) is a Lexmark print server.

Answer (score -1):

You can't MAC address filter such stations according to my knowledge.
PS3 and iPod tend to take on such roles especially when MAC filtered.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question though.